# How can I use folders in a Swift application compiled from the command line?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-package-manager

I'm building a simple webserver using Swift3 and the Swift Package Manager. Running `swift build` in your project folder will build all of the sources found in the `Sources` directory and output an executable. However, I've found that if I create folders within the Sources directory to organize my code, my builds fail. It looks to me like the presence of folders causes swift to treat the source as different modules. Is this the cause, and if so, how can I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Putting directories directly under `Sources` will cause SwiftPM to interpret those as modules. This is described in the [package manager reference](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Reference.md#source-layouts).

To work around this, use another level of indirection: put a directory for your module inside `Sources` and your additional directories inside that directory:

```
Sources/YourApp/Stuff/Source1.swift
Sources/YourApp/Stuff/Source2.swift
Sources/YourApp/MoreStuff/Source3.swift
Sources/YourApp/MoreStuff/Source4.swift
```

Comment: Good going! Although I have to say, I wonder what the justification is for making this the default behavior? It's definitely not intuitive, to say the least.